# Error al usar arrayList, ayuda con la sintaxis del ejercicio

Tags: java, arraylist

Al tratar de recibir los datos del objeto Player para poder enumerarlos aparece un error, mas preciso cuando selecciona la opción 2 en el switch los siguientes errores.

La linea 111 corresponde a

```
          String n= jugadorBaby.get(i).getNombre();
```

La linea 73 corresponde a

```
          muestraPartido(objPartido);

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Test.muestraPartido(Test.java:111)
  at Test.main(Test.java:73)
  C:\Users\Note_Max\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor- 
  snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
  BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Les dejo el código por si me pueden ayudar. Gracias de antemano

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import t.*;
  import java.util.ArrayList;


  public class Test {
  static ArrayList<Partido> partidoBaby = new ArrayList();
  static ArrayList<Player> jugadorBaby = new ArrayList<Player>();
  private static Partido objPartido =new Partido();
  private static Team objTeam =new Team();
  private static Player objPlayer =new Player();
  Team[] team=new Team[6];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int opc,s,e,p,j,t;
     do {
        do {
            menu();
            opc=sc.nextInt();               
        } while (!(opc>0 && opc<6));

        switch(opc)
        {
          case 1:
          sc.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Ingrese el primer jugador del equipo");
          System.out.println("------------------------------------");           
          System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del jugador: ");              
          objPartido.getObjTeam1().getObjPlayer().setNombre(sc.nextLine());
          System.out.print("Ingrese el apellido del jugador: ");

         objPartido.getObjTeam1().getObjPlayer().setApellido(sc.nextLine());
          System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del jugador: ");

         objPartido.getObjTeam1().getObjPlayer().setTamanio(sc.nextFloat());
          System.out.println("------------------------------------");
          jugadorBaby.add(objPartido.getObjTeam1().getArrPlayer()[1]);           
          sc.nextLine();
          //Segundo jugador del primer equipo
          System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo jugador del equipo");
          System.out.println("------------------------------------");
          System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del jugador: ");
          objPartido.getObjTeam1().getObjPlayer().setNombre(sc.nextLine());
          System.out.print("Ingrese el apellido del jugador: ");

         objPartido.getObjTeam1().getObjPlayer().setApellido(sc.nextLine());
          System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del jugador: ");

         objPartido.getObjTeam1().getObjPlayer().setTamanio(sc.nextFloat());
          System.out.println("------------------------------------");
          jugadorBaby.add(objPartido.getObjTeam1().getArrPlayer()[2]); 
          sc.nextLine();                     
          partidoBaby.add(objPartido);
                break;      
            case 2:
                 for(int i=0;i<partidoBaby.size();i++){
                 muestraPartido(objPartido);                   
            }
                break;
            case 3:                  
                break;
            case 4:                                        
                break;
            case 5:
              break;               
        }                
        } while (opc !=5);       
        }        
    public static void menu()
   {
    System.out.println("    ");
    System.out.println("     MENU    ");
    System.out.println("1. Ingresar un nuevo partido, cada uno con dos 
    equipos (Team) y con sus jugadores (Player)" +"asociados");
    System.out.println("2. Listar todos los partidos, junto al nombre de sus 
    dos equipos y jugadores");
    System.out.println("3. Eliminar algún equipo para un partido determinado 
    por su posición dentro de la lista");
    System.out.println("4. Modificar los datos de algún jugador de un equipo 
    de un partido");
    System.out.println("5. Salir del programa (con solicitud de confirmación 
    de salida)");
    System.out.print("Ingrese opcion: ");
    }  // fin menu
    public static void muestraPartido(Partido objPartido)
    {
    System.out.println("Nombre partido: "+objPartido.getNombre());
    System.out.println("========================================");
    System.out.println("Nombre equipo 1 : 
     "+objPartido.getObjTeam1().getNombre());
    System.out.println("***************************************");
    for(int i=0;i<jugadorBaby.size();i++){       
    String n= jugadorBaby.get(i).getNombre();
    String a= jugadorBaby.get(i).getApellido();
    float tam=jugadorBaby.get(i).getTamanio();
    System.out.println("El jugador numero "+(i+1)+" del equipo es: "+n+" 
    "+a+" y su tamaño es de "+tam);

            }  
            }   
}
```

t.Partido

```
package t;

public class Partido {
private String _nombre;
private byte _dia;
private byte _mes;
private byte _anio;
private String mes;
private Team objTeam1;
private Team objTeam2;

public Partido() {
    objTeam1 = new Team();
    objTeam2 = new Team();
}

public String getNombre() {
    return _nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String _nombre) {
    this._nombre = _nombre;
}

public byte getDia() {
    return _dia;
}

public void setDia(byte _dia) {
    this._dia = _dia;
}

public byte getMes() {
    return _mes;
}

public void setMes(byte _mes) {
    this._mes = _mes;
}

public byte getAnio() {
    return _anio;
}

public void setAnio(byte _anio) {
    this._anio = _anio;
}


public Team getObjTeam1() {
    return objTeam1;
}

public void setObjTeam1(Team objTeam1) {
    this.objTeam1 = objTeam1;
}

public Team getObjTeam2() {
    return objTeam2;
}

public void setObjTeam2(Team objTeam2) {
    this.objTeam2 = objTeam2;
 }
 }
```

t.Team

```
 package t;

 public class Team {
 private String _nombre;
 private String _ciudad;
 private Player[] arrPlayer;
 private Player objPlayer;

  public Team() {
    arrPlayer = new Player[6];
    objPlayer= new Player();
}
public Team(String _nombre, String _ciudad, Player[] arrPlayer) {
    this._nombre = _nombre;
    this._ciudad = _ciudad;
    this.arrPlayer = arrPlayer;
}
public String getCiudad() {
    return _ciudad;
}
public void setCiudad(String _ciudad) {
    this._ciudad = _ciudad;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return _nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String _nombre) {
    this._nombre = _nombre;
}
public Player[] getArrPlayer() {
    return arrPlayer;
}
public void setArrPlayer(Player[] v) {
    this.arrPlayer = v;
}
public Player getObjPlayer() {
    return objPlayer;
}
public void setObjPlayer(Player objPlayer) {
    this.objPlayer = objPlayer;
}
}
```

t.Player

```
   package t;

   public class Player {
   private String _nombre;
   private String _apellido;
   private float  _tamanio;

   public Player() {
   }


  public Player(String _nombre, String _apellido, float _tamanio) {
    this._nombre = _nombre;
    this._apellido = _apellido;
    this._tamanio = _tamanio;
 }

 public float getTamanio() {
    return _tamanio;
 }

public void setTamanio(float _tamanio) {
    this._tamanio = _tamanio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return _nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String _nombre) {
    this._nombre = _nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return _apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String _apellido) {
    this._apellido = _apellido;
}
}
```

Comment: muestraPartido es estático, y solamente estás pasando un Partido a el método, y es lo único que conoce. jugadorBaby no existe, por lo tanto arroja NPE.

Comment: Entiendo que pasa un partido, pero no se la forma de hacer que muestre los jugadores de un equipo, no se si me podrías ayudar con eso. Disculpa la demora estaba viajando.

Comment: En la noche te puedo adjuntar una solución, te sirve?